# Install a package manager in FreeBSD 10

Tags: package-management, freebsd

I was trying to install a package using `pkg add`, but I got the reply that

> package manager not installed

To install that I used:

```
tar -C /tmp -zvxf pkg-1.2.1_1.txz
```

and then:

```
/tmp/usr/local/sbin/pkg-static pkg-1.2.1_1.txz
```

It worked out for the first time. But when I rebooted my PC I got an error:

> error exit delayed from previous errors

How to install package manager from FreeBSD installation DVD now?

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't "pkg" standard install on FreeBSD10? I don't use packages, only ports but you shouldn't be installing the package manager that way. Instead you should use ports or the current package manager.

Comment: Even i am not sure of "pkg" being standad installation. But when i dont have the acess to internet installing from the DVD is the only option, no?

Comment: Yes. Is portmaster installed? You can do 'portmaster -L|grep pkg' to see if pkg is installed.

Comment: I know wether pkg is installed or not because whenever i try to install xorg using "pkg add xorg-7.7.txz" i get a reply that "package manager not installed. Do you want to install it [Yes/No]"

Comment: Then install it.

Comment: I have alredy said that i have got no acess to internet. If i choose "yes" then it tries to download the file from its repos and then install it.

Comment: I know this sounds rudimentary, but check your available disk space on your volume(s).

Comment: there is plenty of disk space as i have newly installed this os

Comment: Well, I double checked and pkg is the default so I'm wondering if you messed it up by trying to install it from source. Check the man page to see how to get it to install things from the DVD.

Comment: it may be that.

Comment: found out that pkg needs to get an update. So managed to get access to internet and updates pkg. now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an internet connection, you can install `pkg` using `pkg bootstrap`. This invokes `pkg-static`, fetches and installs the package manager as a binary package.

If you do not want to install a binary package, you can go ahead and build `ports-mgmt/pkg` from the ports tree (http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/pkg):

```
cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg  # adjust to where your ports tree is
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
tar -C / -zvxf pkg-1.2.1_1.txz
```

Yes, remove the `tmp` from the path. Because everything in /tmp will be delete after rebooting.

So when you extract the package to / , the file will reside in:

```
/usr/local/sbin/pkg-static
```

And it will work.