# Installed incompatible pkg version, how to uninstall (or fix otherwise)?

Tags: bsd, pfsense, pkg

While trying to upgrade a pfSense 2.2.6 to the latest version (as described [here](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Upgrading_64-bit_NanoBSD_2.3_to_2.4)) and running `pkg`, I got:

```
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
Do you want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]:
```

After answering Yes, I got:

```
Bootstrapping pkg from pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest, please wait...
Verifying signature with trusted certificate pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301... done
Installing pkg-1.10.5...
Newer FreeBSD version for package pkg:
To ignore this error set IGNORE_OSVERSION=yes
- package: 1003000
- running kernel: 1001000
Allow missmatch now?[Y/n]:
```

I decided to risk it and answered Yes. Ultimately, installation ended with the error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpkg.so.4: Undefined symbol "openat"
```

That presumably means the `pkg` version I got is indeed not compatible with my system. Unfortunately, every further attempt to run `pkg` yields the same error.

How can I get rid of the incompatible `pkg` version again, and how can I get one that is compatible with the BSD version on my pfSense? Or is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed ports? Try to reinstall pkg from ports '/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pkgng has several fallbacks:

- There is a statically-linked version available as `pkg-static`.
- You can run the install tool again by explicitly telling it to `/usr/sbin/pkg bootstrap -f`.

What you need to do is tell `pkg` to use the FreeBSD 10.1 repository.  Because your configuration file says `latest` it is using the FreeBSD 10.3 repository, whose softwares contain various undefined references to library functions that are not found in 10.1 or earlier, including `openat` and `utimensat`.  The 10.1 ABI is not forward compatible with 10.3.

You do this by altering the appropriate `.conf` file in `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/` to say a specific release instead of `latest`, and then re-bootstrapping `pkg`.

Or you can compile your own in the ports tree.  But you'll still be pulling *other* 10.3 software from `latest` if you do.

## Further reading

- [`pkg`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7). *FreeBSD Miscellaneous Information Manual*. 2013-12-12.
- Baptiste Daroussin et al. (2015-10-31). [`pkg`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg).  *FreeBSD System Manager's Manual*.
- Baptiste Daroussin et al. (2015-10-31). [`pkg-static`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-static).  *FreeBSD System Manager's Manual*.
- Baptiste Daroussin et al. (2017-02-02). [`pkg.conf`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg.conf).  *FreeBSD File Formats Manual*.
- [`/usr/local/lib/libpkg.so.3`: Undefined symbol "openat" after upgrade to 1.9.4_1 (FreeBSD 10.1)](https://github.com/freebsd/pkg/issues/1526). FreeBSD `pkg` bug #1526.  2017-01-05.  GitHub.
- [Undefined symbol "utimensat"](https://github.com/bapt/indexinfo/issues/8).  indexinfo bug #8.  2017-01-14.  GitHub.
- [Shared object "libarchive.so.7" not found, required by "pkg"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369372/)
- [Role of the /usr/local directory in FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332764/)
- [Install a package manager in FreeBSD 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124405/)