# FreeBSD 12.1 pkg error: no trusted fingerprints

Tags: package-management, freebsd, pkg

I have just installed FreeBSD 12.1 and want to give it a try. I used qemu.  When I types `pkg`, it started normal bootstrapping. After downloading, it says `No trusted fingerprint found matching package's certificate`. I am confused because there isn't any error ***during*** the installation process. Any ideas? If needed, I will post the log.

At the time of 2020/01/04 10:19:45, I reopened this question.

Now I have seen [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/581050/freebsds-pkg-no-trusted-fingerprint-found-matching-packages-certificate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546983/how-to-solve-pkg-no-trusted-certificates). None of them can help me. 
I tried by building pkg in port: /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg, but it couldn't build. Gives error: `<jemalloc>: jemalloc_arena.c:647: Failed assertion: "nstime_compare(&decay->epoch, &time) <= 0`

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430038/5132 for an example of how to better write a question like this.

Comment: Use `-f` option , `pkg bootstrap -f` , `pkg update -f`...

Comment: @GAD3R well I tried but no, it doesn't work. --fixed typo

Comment: Hello. I still can't resolve this issue. I tried to build the applications I need from ports, but all the ports is depended on ports-mgmt/pkg which fails to build. Which means, I can't install, or even get any sources/binaries. Do you recommend me to report this problem on FreeBSD forum / their support? Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

### Original:

Solved by myself! Changed one line of `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf` to follow: fingerprint: "/dev/null" and it went great!

### Real problem:

It's actually a problem with mac *and* qemu. Running *FreeBSD* on *qemu on Mac* produces this. Any other host or guest system and any other virtualizing software won't have this problem.

Comment: This is bad. You have disabled signature checks of download packages.

Comment: This is an old post... It's actually a problem with mac *and* qemu. Running *FreeBSD* on *qemu on Mac* produces this problem. Any other host or guest system and any other virtualizing software won't produce this problem. I have to update the answer